# How to construct a “toy” version of the Ascon permutation?

Tags: algorithm-design

I want to obtain a “toy” version of the [Ascon permutation](https://tinycrypt.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/ascon-permutation-function/) defined for five 8-bit words (instead of five 64-bit words.) It seems that it is possible to use the same bit-sliced 5-bit S-Box. But is it possible to use the same sequence of constants (`0xF0, 0xE1, 0xD2, ...`) XORed with the middle word? And what is a suitable example of a set of five different 8-bit linear diffusion functions?

Comment: please define the permutation in the question so it is easy to follow what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you want your "toy" version?  The reason I ask is because the parts of the "toy" Ascon is analogous to the full version would depend on the reason you wanted the toy version.  If it's to attempt to do cryptanalysis on the toy version (with hopes that gives insight to the full one), well, that's nontrivial, as it wouldn't be obvious how to cut the full version down without changing the crypto-relevant parts - there's a reason we study reduced round versions of ciphers; reducing the rounds has a known effect.

Comment: @poncho: The function is intended to provide a suitable example of an algorithm that answers the question stated in Chapter 2.3 of the paper [“LS-Designs: Bitslice Encryption for Efficient Masked Software Implementations”](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/LS-Designs%3A-Bitslice-Encryption-for-Efficient-Grosso-Leurent/d8c6777a081af0cb9d2147da2bc2207f1f771c01): 5-bit S-box and 8-bit L-box. It is not intended to give insight to the full Ascon permutation function.